# Java args command line parameter-- trying to pass filename as parameter in args to a method but not working

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm fairly new to Java. Currently trying to have the filename given in args[] passed to this FileReader but when I compile it says it can't find the specified file. If I hardcode the filename it works fine. How's this supposed to work?

```
public class StringSplit
{

   public void parseCommands
   {
     try
     {
       //not working, why? It works if I do FileReader fr= new FileReader("hi.tpl").
       FileReader fr= new FileReader(args);

     }

 public static void main (String[] args)// args holds the filename to be given to FileReader
 {
  if (args.length==0)
   {
     System.out.println("Error: Bad command or filename. Syntax: java [filename.tpl]);
     System.exit(0)
   }
   StringSplit ss= new StringSplit();
   ss.parseCommands();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your args parameter is not visible to parseCommands.

Plus args is an array. You probably want to send the first element in that array to parseCommands.

```
public void parseCommands(String fileName)
   {
     try
     {
       //not working, why? It works if I do FileReader fr= new FileReader("hi.tpl").
       FileReader fr= new FileReader(fileName);

     }
  }

public static void main (String[] args)// args holds the filename to be given to FileReader
 {
  if (args.length==0)
   {
     System.out.println("Error: Bad command or filename. Syntax: java [filename.tpl]);
     System.exit(0)
   }
   StringSplit ss= new StringSplit();
   ss.parseCommands(args[0]);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You've only given pseudo-code to start with, but fundamentally you need to learn about the different types of variable in Java.

`args` in `main` is a *parameter* - it's local to that method. If you want another method to be able to use its value then either you need to store that value in a shared variable (e.g. a static or instance variable) or you need to pass it as an argument to the method which needs it.

For example:

```
public class StringSplit
{
  public void parseCommands(String[] files)
  {
    try
    {
      FileReader fr= new FileReader(files[0]);

    }
    // Rest of code
 }

 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    if (args.length==0)
    {
      System.out.println("...");
      System.exit(0)
    }
    StringSplit ss= new StringSplit();
    ss.parseCommands(args);
  }
}
```

(At the moment you could also make `parseCommands` a static method and then call it without creating an instance of `StringSplit`, btw...)

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you don't need to create an object to call a function if you're in the object already. Second, pass the args as a parameter to your split function.